# Как ускорить отправку 3х GET-запросов

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, requests, get

Всем привет!
есть 3 GET-запроса

```
r1 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=666&userage=18')
r2 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=777&userage=22')
r3 = requests.get('http://mysite.com/check.php?' + 'userid=888&userage=26')
```

на их отправку и получение ответа уходит слишком много времени, как это время уменьшить? Эти три запроса тормозят работу всей программы

Comment: http://www.eamonnbell.com/blog/2015/10/05/the-right-way-to-use-requests-in-parallel-in-python/

Comment: Будьте осторожны, за слишком частые запросы администратор сервера вас забанит нафиг :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов это использование asyncio.

```
import asyncio
import requests

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=666&userage=18')
    future2 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=777&userage=22')
    future3 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=888&userage=26')
    response1 = await future1
    response2 = await future2
    response3 = await future3
    print(response1.text)
    print(response2.text)
    print(response3.text)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Подробно описано вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio)

UPDATED.
Если нужно задать заголовки, то можно использовать `functools.partial`:

```
future1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(requests.get, 'http://httpbin.org/get', headers={'Test': '1'}))
```

Или же вариант с aiohttp:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, headers={'key': 'value'}) as response:
        return await response.read()

async def run():
    urls = (
        'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=666&userage=18',
        'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=777&userage=22',
        'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=888&userage=26',
    )

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [
            asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url, session))
            for url in urls
        ]
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(responses)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Кроме того можно рассмотреть кэширование результатов запроса (если контекст задачи позволяет) например при помощи redis (https://github.com/vivekn/redis-simple-cache как вариант).

```
from redis_cache import cache_it, SimpleCache


my_cache = SimpleCache(expire=60)


@cache_it(cache=my_cache)
def get_data(url):
    ...
```

Comment: Можно было бы и aiohttp тогда для приличия посоветовать)

Comment: смущает loop- запросы не будут идти циклично до бесконечности?

Comment: @babyborn это не тот loop, о котором вы подумали, не будут :)

Comment: еще вопрос, если есть необходимость прописать headers, как это сделать?  future1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.get, 'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=666&userage=18', headers = headers) не прошло

Comment: Обновил ответ с заголовками

Comment: опробовал, работает как часы, но особого прироста к скорости отправки запросов я не заметил :(

Answer (score 2):

Запросы можно через потоки распараллелить.

После прогона всех элементов, результаты будут в `results`:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool


urls = [
    'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=666&userage=18',
    'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=777&userage=22',
    'http://mysite.com/check.php?userid=888&userage=26',
]

pool = ThreadPool()
results = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
print(results)
```

---

**PS.** Хоть `multiprocessing` и относится к обработке в процессах, его модуль `multiprocessing.dummy` работает через потоки.

**PPS.** В `results` будет храниться результат выполнения `requests.get(url)`, поэтому можно после обработать, например:

```
for x in results:
    print(x, len(x.content), x.content)
```

Comment: после некоторого количества циклов, вылезла ошибка Runtime error: cant start new thread, как я понимаю из  за того, что потоки не закрывались

Comment: @babyborn, какая ошибка?

Comment: обновил коммент

Comment: а какой размер у urls? Только что создавал 1 000 000 элементов (без запроса по сети, просто `len`) и нормально

Comment: в данный момент 20. в threading была такая фишка как join, тут есть что то подобное?

Comment: угу, в `map`. Как я писал, map вернет список результата т.е. пока все элементы не обработаются дальше map не пойдет код. Есть подозрение, что в вашем случае может не хватает оперативы. А сколько ее у вас? Кст, в `ThreadPool()` можно передавать количество потоков, например: `ThreadPool(4)`, если не задавать, то будет, вроде бы, количество_ядер * 2